# How can I save a video, audio in an NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc

What I have is to save phone numbers and text, but I am missing the one to save video or launch an app with NFC.
method to save a url or phone number

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZec8.png][1]

Comment: public NdefMessage createUriMessage(String content, String type) {
        NdefRecord record = NdefRecord.createUri(type + content);
        NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{record});
        return msg;

    }

Answer (score 0):

Most Cards do not have the storage space for audio or video files, therefore there is no standard for this.

I think the biggest card available at the moment is 4Kb.

As you have already commented on your own question of how to create a URL (linking to audio or video files or other web address).
With https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord#createUri(android.net.Uri)

`NdefRecord ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createUri("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEp-ejKyXVw");`

The full NFC standard for URL Ndef records is available at https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-RTD_URI_1.0.pdf

To launch an Android App you can also add an AAR Ndef record to the Ndef message https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#aar

and
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord#createApplicationRecord(java.lang.String)

Comment: How can I select the video (video url) that I want to write to the nfc card?

Comment: Choosing a video is up to you, to NFC it is just another URL like any other web page e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEp-ejKyXVw  and you have already defined how to create an Ndef message for URL's

Comment: How should I modify the createUri? so that I select a video from the mobile and generate the URL of the video to record it in the Nfc tag

Comment: Updated with example the `createUri` just takes the URL string (this string needs to be a web address that is on the internet to share with other users, e.g. from youtube or any other internet video hosting service), it should not be confused with things like local file based URI's e.g. `content://` , `file://` while valid they have no meaning and will not be accessible to other people who read the card.

Comment: exactly what I want is that, the local directory to write the path of a video of my mobile (local directory) to be able to reproduce when I need it

Comment: how would i to be able to access files and get the url of the video?

Comment: Getting a local URI from something like MediaStore or Storage Access Framework is out of scope of the question as it has nothing to do with NFC, while technically you could store that URI on an NFC card, it would only have any meaning really to the phone that created it and thus you might as well store it on the phone instead of on a NFC card.